# How to use the "BufferGeometryUtils.js" for three.js?

Tags: three.js

Although I am not a pro in javascript, I've been using three.js for a few months (I juste have the "three.js" script in my main folder) and I wanted to use a function from BufferGeometryUtils. I tried with the same technic but it didn't work and I got this error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: BufferGeometry is not defined at Object.mergeBufferGeometries (BufferGeometryUtils.js:202)" (my version of three.js is only a few weeks old). I saw another post about this problem but it didn't work for me as it was an older version of Three.js. So how can I use these functions in my script please ?

Comment: could you include a small piece of code that would replicated this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to work ok.
It must be a way in which you are including the files or maybe you are transpiling?
Your question really does not have enough details.

```js
var geometry1 = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry( 5, 32 );
var geometry2 = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry( 5, 32 );
var merged = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries([geometry1, geometry2]);
console.log(merged);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/r104/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/r104/examples/js/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I know I didn't give enough details but your answer helped me resolve my problem anyway : I used the script directly from github as you did instead of the downloaded one from the site and it worked !

Comment: i am using BufferGeometryUtils but the geometries are merged at the same position.. i want each of them to be merged with offset position. is there any way

Answer (score 9):

`THREE.BufferGeometryUtils` is no part of the core but you can easily import the utils like so:

```
 import { BufferGeometryUtils } from 'three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js';
```

As you can see, the class is part of the `JSM` library which means it's available as a module.

`three.js R104`

Comment: Small note that this has recently been changed ([see here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#131--132)) to `import * as BufferGeometryUtils from './jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js';`

Comment: I thought we were supposed to drop the .js extension when importing a module. So confused right now